# Python architecture with flask

Tags: python, flask

This is a general question regarding how I structure some flask code and I am unsure exactly how to even title this question.

I have a flask application and a number of endpoints, at typical one is shown below:

```
@module_bp.errorhandler(401)
def unauthorized(_error='Unauthorized') -> flask.Response:
    """Response"""
    return pre_make_response(401, _error)  # this is a wrapper on flask.make_response()

@module_bp.route(f'{route_prefix}run-future/', methods=['GET'])
def run_future_get() -> flask.Response:
    auth_result = check_auth(request)  # returns custom object
    if not auth_result.is_authorized:
        return unauthorized(auth_result.response)

    team_id = request.args.get('team_id', None)
    vr = external_functions.run_future_get(auth_result.email, team_id)
    return velo_response_dispatch(vr)
```

I am repeating the same three lines in most, but not every endpoint:

```
    auth_result = check_auth(request)  # returns custom object
    if not auth_result.is_authorized:
        return unauthorized(auth_result.response)
```

This is annoying right now as if I change something with unathorized response, I then need to perform the same multi-line find-and-replace on every endpoint, and there are about 30 of them.

It's not a big deal, but I was wondering if there are some elegant solutions such as a oneliner that I am missing.

Comment: To do things like check authentication, it can be a good idea to create a decorator. That way you can avoid code duplication within lots of functions and methods. [Interesting post from Flask about decorators](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/patterns/viewdecorators/)

Answer (score 1):

For this special case, if you want to run a function every time before the real endpoint logic is executed you can use the `before_request` decorator as described [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/?highlight=before_request#flask.Flask.before_request)

Of course this is only helpful if you want to reject every unauthorized request to your application.